# Invalid file descriptor problem with Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, version-control, push

I've been using Git on Linux for about a year, and everything works fine. Since recently, a colleague has joined development and he's using Windows. Everything works fine there as well, but sometimes when he tries to push changes to a remote repository (bare) on Linux server it bails out with 'Invalid file descriptor' message.

I update the same remote repository using Linux git without any problems. We tried WinGit 0.2 and [MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (downloaded today, uses Git 1.5.6). Both have the same problem.

I should mention that network is working without any problems. I can clone the whole repository again from scrach. I just cannot push any changes to it.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have problem with your anti virus. I had the same problem on my machine, I was(still) use nod32, just disable thread protection module IMON, that could fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a git user so this is a complete guess: has the TCP connection been broken?  Try capturing network traffic with Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

git on Win32 is known to be iffy. Have you tried the [latest msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)? It's a port of 1.6.0.2 (released September 23rd.) Also, is there any way you could get a more verbose / trace output from the failing git command?

Comment: The latest msysgit is still 1.5.6. Where did you find it's 1.6.0.2?

Comment: On its Google Code download page here: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list . The direct download link for Git-1.6.0.2-preview20080923.exe is this: http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.6.0.2-preview20080923.exe